# Is it possible to use arrow key in lex yacc ?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I developed for my university a mini-shell. For parse the command line I use lex and yacc.

When I press up/down/left/right arrow the string "^[[A or B or C or D is displayed.

Is it possible to recognize this character for execute action when this key is pressed ? Maybe using the functions of ncurses library (I'm in Linux)?

I show, the bash use yacc grammar ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison )  and we can use the arrow key. So I think is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: The handling of arrow keys etc is wholly separate from Lex or Yacc.  It involves working with terminal modes (raw and cooked), which is something that `ncurses` does handle — or you may want to look at the GNU Readline library (which is closer to what is used by Bash, I believe). Note that different terminal types send different character sequences for up-arrow; you may need some of the facilities from termcap or terminfo to handle the terminal dependencies.

Comment: Keys are behavioral items, not lexical/grammatical items. To put it another way, your shell's scanner translates input that it receives into tokens, and your shell's grammar then uses those tokens to evaluate an expression. Arrow keys don't generate input unless you change terminal modes as explained by Jonathan Leffler, so your scanner won't receive them as input.

Comment: You can embed readlink within your program, or simply install rlwrap and run `rlwrap ./my-mini-shell` to get the behavior without any change.

Answer (score 4):

You could...

Essentially, **`yacc`** provides you with a state machine using *terminal* tokens (symbolic constants) provided by **`lex`**.  Think of it as a big `switch` statement.

The arrow-keys returned by *curses* (***if*** you call [**`keypad`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad)) are defined in the *curses* header file as symbolic constants, e.g., **`KEY_UP`**, **`KEY_HOME`**, etc.  There's a list in the [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Predefined-key-codes) manual page.

The *curses* library reads the character sequences, using its own state machine, matches the sequences against the terminal description and returns the constants.

Whether you get constants from **`lex`** or **`curses`** doesn't really matter much.  yacc doesn't care.  Also, whether you even use **`lex`** in this case, or just call **getch** directly may not matter (depending on how you have organized your program).

But most people wouldn't bother with lex/yacc for parsing editing sequences on the input buffer.